# trying to use single condition in sorting datagrid view column

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, datagridview, linq-to-entities

I am using below function if i click the datagrid view column header the entire datagrid view column will be sorted ....

```
private void dgvproducts_ColumnHeaderMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
   if (order == "d")
   {
        //order by ascending
        order = "a";
       dgvproducts.DataSource = dbcontext.products
           .GroupBy(x => x.product_Id)
           .Select(a => new
             {
                    productid = a.Key,
                    prouctnam = a.FirstOrDefault().product_Name,
                    productimage = a.FirstOrDefault().product_Image,
                    productdescr = a.FirstOrDefault().product_Description,
                    stockavailable = a.LongCount(),
                    productprice = a.FirstOrDefault().product_Price
             }).OrderBy(a=>a.prouctnam).ToList();
    }
    else
    {
        // order by descending
        order = "d";
        dgvproducts.DataSource = dbcontext.products
            .GroupBy(x => x.product_Id)
            .Select(a => new
         {
                  productid = a.Key,
                  prouctnam = a.FirstOrDefault().product_Name,
                  productimage = a.FirstOrDefault().product_Image,
                  productdescr = a.FirstOrDefault().product_Description,
                  stockavailable = a.LongCount(),
                  productprice = a.FirstOrDefault().product_Price
         }).OrderByDescending(a => a.prouctnam).ToList();

    }
}
```

this is working fine....

what i want, is there any posibility to check single condition and binding datagrid view at once ...

instead of doing two times......

Many thanks in advance for any ideas....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could refactor and only apply the order part later - this way you avoid most of the duplicated code:

```
var products = dbcontext.products
                        .GroupBy(x => x.product_Id)
                        .Select(a => new
                        {
                            productid = a.Key,
                            prouctnam = a.FirstOrDefault().product_Name,
                            productimage = a.FirstOrDefault().product_Image,
                            productdescr = a.FirstOrDefault().product_Description,
                            stockavailable = a.LongCount(),
                            productprice = a.FirstOrDefault().product_Price
                        });

if (order == "d")
{
    order = "a";
    dgvproducts.DataSource = products.OrderBy(a=>a.prouctnam).ToList();
}
else
{
    order = "d";
    dgvproducts.DataSource = products.OrderByDescending(a=>a.prouctnam).ToList();
}
```

Comment: Or you can just use products.Reverse() instead of products.OrderByDescending(a=>a.prouctnam).ToList() :D

Comment: @Ace: That would imply they are ordered by product name already, which is not a given